# Facebook API feed dialog - prevent unnecessary click

Tags: facebook

hi,

Using Facebook's API it's possible to prompt a user to post to his/her wall using the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). However, using the javascript SDK, this requires two clicks: one on the button which brings up the dialog, the other on the "Share" button within the dialog.

Is it possible to get rid of one of these clicks? I thought of two approaches:

- Embedding the dialog within an iframe, as Facebook provides a URL for a full page dialog. That will require the user to click only on the "Share" button. Apparently Facebook blocks that option.
- Using an access token and `display=iframe`, but I want to avoid the user having to authorize my application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to use fb.api instead.

```
function PostToMyWall(){

        FB.login(function(response)
        {
            if (response.authResponse)
            {

                  //Post to my wall
                  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { 
                  message: lnk,link: lnk

                  }, 
                  function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                     // //alert('Error occured');

                   } else {
                     // //alert("Successfully Posted to My Wall!");

                    }
                  });}else
            {
                alert('Not logged in');
            }}, { scope : 'publish_stream' });
         }
```

My application got a similar function, check it out at www.wootube.woolei.com - "Post to WooTube Page and Group"

or popup when the page using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {   FB.ui({method: 'feed',
            name: mdtxt,
            link: lnk,
            picture: hackImageUrl(img,fld),
            caption: '<?php echo $clickme; ?>',
            description: '<?php echo $app_desc; ?>'
        }, 
         function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
             alert('Error occured');

          } else {
             alert("Successfully Posted to Group");

           }
         });});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that would require my application to be authorized by the user, which I want to avoid.

Comment: hi johnny, i just update the code to pop up the dialog, so it reduce to 1 click i guess? :)

Comment: I'm guessing that will trigger the browser's pop-up blocker, so the user won't see the pop-up at all.